# A type for functions that pipe into each other

Tags: haskell

I want to deal with an abstraction where I can store f1, f2, f3, f4, f5... where

```
:t f5 . f4 . f3 . f2 . f1
-- String -> Int
```

I don't much care for the intermediary results, so I would like to do something like:

```
data PipeFunction a z = [(a->b), (b->c), ..., (y->z)] -- pseudocode
```

What kind of abstractions would allow me to do this? Right now the only thing I can think of is:

```
newtype PipeFunction a b c = PipeFunction (a->b, c->d)
```

but I would like it to be for arbitrary number of functions.

EDIT: A potentially illustrating example/use case, having an abstraction that allows me to perform this more elegantly:
[image: reactive app example]

EDIT2: Follow-up. Is it possible to swap out elements of a type-aligned sequence? Working off of something like this:

```
swapPipe :: PipeFunction a z -> Int -> (b -> c) -> PipeFunction a z
swapPipe Nil _ _ = Nil
swapPipe (f :> fs) i g = f :> swapPipe fs i g
swapPipe (f :> fs) 0 g = g :> fs
```

Would dependent types in something like Idris be of use?

Comment: Can you share more of the context? Like, once you find a way to store these functions, what are you going to do with them?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I want to read in a string like "head . head . group . sort" and get a list of functions that pipe into each other, so that I can evaluate them separately. I have added an example.

Comment: A search term that might be useful is "type-aligned sequence".

Comment: Ehem, or Free category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store them with a GADT, like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data PipeFunction a z where
  Nil :: PipeFunction a a
  (:>) :: Show b => (a -> b) -> PipeFunction b z -> PipeFunction a z

infixr 5 :>
```

And the example from your question:

```
import Data.Function
import Data.List

showPipe :: PipeFunction a z -> a -> [String]
showPipe Nil _ = []
showPipe (f :> fs) x = show y : showPipe fs y
  where y = f x

main = print $ showPipe (sort :> group :> sortBy (flip compare `on` length) :> head :> head :> Nil) [3,1,2,2,3,5,5,6,3,5,5,3]

-- Result: ["[1,2,2,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,6]","[[1],[2,2],[3,3,3,3],[5,5,5,5],[6]]","[[3,3,3,3],[5,5,5,5],[2,2],[1],[6]]","[3,3,3,3]","3"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to swap out an element of such data structure? For instance, doing tail instead of head in the example.

Since the type signature of the intermediary element is not present encoded in the type signature of the abstraction (i.e. PipeFunction), would this not be possible?

Comment: Edited the question to include more context.